# Adding New Parameters to a Child Class in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been writing a game that has a subclass of the SKSpriteNode with some extra functions and variables. I'd like to set some of the variables when the object is created eg

```
let mySprite = MySubclass (width: 24, height 33)
```

I'm not sure this is possible which means I'll probably have to call a methos of the subclass to set the vars in a separate stage which is a bit clunky:

```
let mySprite = MySubclass ()
mySprite.setSize(24, height: 33)
```

Any ideas how I can do this in a more elegant way?

Many Thanks,
Kw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very fundamental OOP. Here is how you do it in Swift:

```
class MySubClass: SKSpriteNode {
    var width: CGFloat       // Declare your own properties
    var height: CGFloat      // ...

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width   // set up your own properties
        self.height = height // ...
        super.init()         // call up to the super-class's init to set up its properties 
    }
}
```

Have you read Apple's book [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)? It's free and clearly covers this...

Comment: Many thanks. I read something on her that suggested that this couldn't be done, but I must have misinterpreted the post.